# Fixing rebased commits in git flow develop/master branches

Tags: git, git-flow

I've messed up my commit history big time. I was testing some cron jobs, and I've commited with the wrong dates. So i have commits with time stamps 2 days in the future, then back to the present. Whats even worse, i have already merged the feature with the commits to both develop and master, and even based another feature on top of it :')
I've looked up that I can edit the dates of commits doing a `git rebase -i -p` and then amending the offending commits, but after I change all those commits into new ones, whats going to happen with the other branches that already have the 'old version' of the rebased commits? This has been already pushed, and i'm the only developer in this project.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need to force-push all branches that are descendants of the borked commits.

Comment: But after I rebase one of the branches, do I merge those new commits into the other branches again before force push?